# array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a function `loadNotes` in a Controller called `edit_flow.php`

```
function loadNotes_get() {
   $object = json_decode($this->input->post("inputJson"), true);
   if (array_key_exists('subject_id', $object) && array_key_exists('teacher_id', $object))
   {
       $this->response($object);
   }
}
```

I'm calling the above function when the page is rendered.

My JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   loadNotes();
});

function loadNotes() {
   var data = '{"subject_id":'+subject_id+',"teacher_id":'+teacher_id+'}';
   ajaxRequest(data, 'loadNotes', 'GET');   // GET request on loadNotes
}
```

The code for the JavaScript function `ajaxRequest` is:

```
function ajaxRequest(datum, method_url, request_type) {
   var eurl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>edit_flow/" + method_url;
   var params = 'inputJson=' + datum; 

   var request = $.ajax({
       type: request_type,
       url: eurl,
       data: params,
       success: function(result) {
          console.log('result: '+result);
          console.log('data: '+params);
       },
       async: false
   });

   return request.responseText;
}
```

Console output from `ajaxRequest` function:

```
result: <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/edit_flow.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 126</p>

</div>
data: inputJson={"subject_id":1234,"teacher_id":111}
```

The problem is pointed to the controller `edit_flow.php`, but can't seem to resolve this even after debugging it. The console outputs an error instead of the `object` itself.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you calling method trough `GET` & using `POST` to retrieve the data & hence object is NULL.

Comment: `var data = '{"subject_id":` doesn't look right, why a string?

Comment: your `$object` is assigned null values so `array_key_exists` function read array as null that why the error shown

Comment: Trace the error back. If `$object` is `null`, that means `json_decode` failed, which means the input to it was incorrect... Hunt your own bugs, don't just post on SO.

Comment: why you can't check is_array($object) ?

Comment: @deceze Tracking down bugs is something that is learnt with experience, don't knock someone for getting stuck with code, is that not the whole point of SO? Why do people downvote so readily without an explanation. He's given us a perfectly reasonable question, included his code and also included the error. Help him!

Comment: I hate when people dis-vote without any explanation. We all are learning here.

Comment: @Rikesh if you look carefully at the function `ajaxRequest` in `loadNotes` function I have passed `GET`. So how is it that i'm doing a `POST`?

Comment: From line `$this->input->post("inputJson");` it seems that you retrivng using POST

Comment: @Mark I guess I mean *"kick the can down the street a little further"*. The error message is quite clear, even a simple `echo $object` should have pointed a little more in the right direction. The downvote button says "doesn't show enough research effort", which I feel here. Yes, experience is necessary, but a question that says "I get this error message, here's all my code" deserves a downvote IMO.

Comment: @deceze thanks for pointing that out. I will improve my postings next time :)

Comment: @deceze That's your opinion. IMO, SO has an overall air of negativity, which for a site which is suppose to support and help users seems a little strange to me

Comment: @Mark I don't disagree. I'm trying to be supportive where possible, but after seeing so many questions which are just terrible, you become a little jaded. h4kl0rd: Thanks, please do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function loadNotes_get() {
   $object = json_decode($this->input->get("inputJson"), true);
   if (array_key_exists('subject_id', $object) && array_key_exists('teacher_id', $object))
   {
       $this->response($object);
   }
}
```

Or change you JS to POST instead of GET

```
function loadNotes() {
   var data = '{"subject_id":'+subject_id+',"teacher_id":'+teacher_id+'}';
   ajaxRequest(data, 'loadNotes', 'POST');   // POST request on loadNotes
}
```

Comment: It still throwing the same error after modifying the code to `$this->input->get(("inputJson"), true)`

Comment: Can you print the $this->input variable using print_r($this->input);

Comment: It outputs the json `result: {"subject_id":1234,"teacher_id":111}` that is after running `$this->response($this->input->get('inputJson'))`

Comment: Can you do $this->response($object)

Comment: that won't work, since the json is getting passed as a parameter in `.../edit_flow/loadNotes?inputJson={}`

Comment: Yeah but you can call the php file directly and see what it outputs.. no?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48041/discussion-between-sajith-nair-and-h4kl0rd)

Comment: What I am trying to find out is whether your json_decode worked or not. There can be a case where the GET request gets urlencoded or json sting might get slashes added to it like {\"subject\":1234, in which case json parsing will fail, and you will need to use stripslashes

Answer (score -1):

check if the second param is an array.
you have to pass an array into the second param to the method array_key_exists()

Parameters for the method :

key
Value to check.
array
An array with keys to check.